# Put on action html Route to my controller

Tags: c#, routes

Good afternoon,

I want to create a route to my Create Controller. How do I do it? I' ve seen code like this

```
@Url.RouteUrl( "Create", new { action = "Create"} )
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Root",
    url: "index.html",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

But I'm not able to use it

```
<form method="POST" action='@Url.RouteUrl( "Create", new { action = "Create"} )' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input placeholder="Nome" name="nome" type="text">
    <input placeholder="Password" name="senha" type="password">
    <input placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email">
    <button type="submit">Submeter</button>
</form>
```

and this is my Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Usuario usuario)
{
    if (usuario == null)
        return BadRequest();

    usuarioRepositorio.Add(usuario);

    return CreatedAtRoute(new {id=usuario.UsuarioId}, usuario); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this `action='@Url.Action("Create", "Usuarios")'` where first need action and after the name of controller